# Wordpress Custom Gutenberg Block render_callback doesnt render

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to build a custom Gutenberg Block, which will be rendered dynamically (from PHP).
I've spent a significant amount of time searching for different solutions, minimized my code to the absolutely necessary, and still it doesnt work.

My main reference is this page: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/

And here's my code:
PHP (functions.php):

```
function register_test_block(){

    wp_register_script('test-block',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/test-block.js',
        array('wp-blocks') );

    register_block_type('test/testblock', array(
            'render_callback' => function( $block_attributes, $content ) {
                return '<p>OMG SUCCESS!</p>';
            },
            'editor_script' => 'test-block' )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'register_test_block');
```

test-block.js:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;


registerBlockType('test/testblock', {
    title: 'test block',
    edit: props => {
        return (<p>test</p>);
    },
    save: props => {
        return null;
    }
});
```

i really have no idea why this isn't working as its supposed to, on the frontend the block is just not rendered at all, not even a comment or anything. Oh and my current WP Version is 5.5.3 with PHP 7.3 if this helps..

Does anyone know why my block isn't rendering? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is on the right path as you do need to register the block both in JavaScript and PHP. The missing link to make it work is that in the JavaScript edit() function, the actual rendering of the PHP callback function is done via `<ServerSideRender>` component, eg:

test-block.js:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { serverSideRender: ServerSideRender } = wp;

registerBlockType('test/testblock', {
    title: 'test block',
    edit: () => {
        return (
            <>
                <ServerSideRender
                    block="test/testblock"
                />
            </>
        );
    },
    save() {
        return null; // Nothing to save here..
    }
});
```

functions.php

```
function register_test_block(){
    wp_register_script('test-block', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test-block.js', array(
        'wp-blocks',
        'wp'
    ));

    register_block_type('test/testblock', array(
        'render_callback' => 'test_testblock_renderer'
        'editor_script' => 'test-block' //re-added, see comment below
    ));
}

// Optional: Moved render callback to separate function to keep logic clear
function test_testblock_renderer($block_attributes, $content){
    return '<p>OMG SUCCESS!</p>';
}

add_action('init', 'register_test_block');
```

There are many more useful attributes that are part of the [ServerSideRender](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-server-side-render/) component for building dynamic blocks, however: its a legacy component and if you are building a new data-driven block for Gutenberg, it would be best to see if you are able to achieve your goals via the [REST API endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/) where possible.

Comment: Thanks, using serverSideRender, still nothing is displayed in frontend and der editor block shows: "Error loading block: Invalid block.".. any ideas? I suppose the render_callback in php doesnt work properly, but I do not get why...

Comment: AND if I remove `'editor_script'` from `register_block_type` the js wont be executed at all? where do I have to enqueue the js script?

Comment: @Schnurbert Once you've updated Javascript code, make sure you clear your browser cache so the block validation matches current code. Also, open the browser console and see if there is any error logged.  Delete the block from the editor and re-add the block clean and see if there is any issue.

Comment: To answer the second question: the Javascript is loaded via PHP via `wp_register_script('test-block' ..)` which then renders the `edit: () => {...}` of test-block.js. The Javascript `edit()` function contains the `ServerSideRender` which then calls PHP and returns the render_callback function contents.

Comment: Re-added 'editor_script' as per https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/wp-plugin/ apologies for any confusion.. updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Really appreciate your help S.Walsh!
Cleaning the browsercache or reentering the block didn't really help. Then I rearranged some files, changed some function names, and suddenly it works.
Here's my current js (if someone gets the same problem):

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { serverSideRender: ServerSideRender } = wp;

const { Fragment } = wp.element;

registerBlockType('abc/dynamicblock', {
    title: 'dynamicblock',
    description: 'dynamicblock',
    icon: (<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><rect width="24" height="24" style={{fill:'rgb(0,121,200)'}} /></svg>),
    category: 'abc',
    edit: props => {
        return <Fragment>
            <p>serverSideRender should appear here:</p>
            <ServerSideRender
                block={ "abc/dynamicblock" } />
        </Fragment>;
    },
    save: props => {
        return null; // Nothing to save here..
    }
});
```

and this is the php part:

```
function register_dynamicblock(){

    wp_register_script('dynamicblock',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/js/dynamicblock.js',
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-element'),
        time() );

    $re = register_block_type('abc/dynamicblock', array(
        'render_callback' => 'dynamicblock_renderer',
        'title' => 'dynamicblock',
        'editor_script' => 'dynamicblock'
    ));

}
add_action('init', 'register_dynamicblock');

function dynamicblock_renderer(){
    return '<div>success!</div>';
}
```